# SQL Input Box Not Appear in phpmyadmin 4.6.0

Tags: phpmyadmin

i was try latest `phpmyadmin 4.6.0` version, on sql tab a white box to input sql command its disappeared like this [images one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p43Ed.png)

but on `phpmyadmin 4.4.15` its normal you can see white box appear like this [images two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUsOd.png)

anyone please help, thanks before.
regards.

Comment: Is this still happening? Can you check your webserver error log for any hints? Which web browser are you using? Can you clear your browser cache and try again? Does it happen also on the demo server at https://demo.phpmyadmin.net ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.
As workaround try to disable CodeMirror in Page-related settings for SQL input box page:

1. Click on Settings in top right corner of SQL page
2. Uncheck "Enable CodeMirror"

Now SQL input box should appear normally however SQL autocomplete feature won't work.

Anyway root cause for my case was that HTTP server wasn't properly configured to serve .js and .css files with proper MIME types.
In case of Lighttpd config was missing:

include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl"

Upon including this line in Lighttpd config file and restarting Lighttpd everything is working flawlessly.